# How to add a Skype indicator?

Tags: indicator, skype

I've installed Skype, but the icon is not shown at the top panel (tray). As "tray-whitelist" was removed from dconf, I can't add icon by myself.

Comment: It should be present under the messaging menu, which makes it easy to access and view all email and chat clients. However, if you don't like it, sni-qt:i386 is the way to go

Comment: @Vic It is not duplication, since another answer works only in < 12.10. In 13.04 "tray-whitelist" was removed. That's why your one won't help on systems >=13.04

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I had the same problem, installing the following package fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Comment: Worked on 13.10 as well!

Comment: Worked on 14.04 as well :)

Comment: after logging in it is disappearing... it came back again!

Comment: if skype's icon is disappearing after loggin, you have to kill 'indicator-application-service' and it will appear again.

Comment: Needed a restart to work.

Comment: Worked on 14.10 as well!

Comment: More info on why this works: http://askubuntu.com/a/151118/48105

Comment: works on 15.05 too

Comment: ... and it works on 12.04 too !

Comment: Works on 15.10, no restart necessary.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: installed the 64bit as well - just in case - `sudo apt-get install sni-qt sni-qt:i386`

Comment: works in 16.04 too

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem when I downloaded skype directly from skype.com.

To fix it just you need completely remove your installed skype, then open terminal and do this:

> 1. sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
> 2. sudo apt-get update
> 3. sudo apt-get install skype && sudo apt-get -f install

After these manipulations I have skype icon in panel.

Comment: Its always a bit older version, but a good solution to a given problem

Answer (score 3):

Skype icon can be visible after white listing the skype icon by `gsetting set` command like,

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier', 'Skype']"
```

Found on Linuxicle : [Enable skype notification icon in Ubuntu 12.04/13.04](http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/07/enable-skype-notification-icon-in.html)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.
(Using Ubuntu 12.04.4)

Comment: From Ubuntu 13.04 on, this solution will not work as the support for systray-whitelist was removed ([see](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/974480/comments/5)). You can however [install the systray-white PPA's packages](http://askubuntu.com/a/368549/107321) to make this solution work again.

Answer (score 0):

This have worked for me: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/fix-skype-not-working-in-ubuntu-1304.html
Nvidia and Catalyst drivers don't run well with skype.

Answer (score -4):

I also had problems installing Skype from skype.com. I had tried to install the Ubuntu 12.04 multiarch version that seemed to be the closest they had to the one I was running which was Ubuntu 13.04 on a x86_64 (64 bit) machine. Had problems with both the sound and video and my 13.04 was a clean and recent install.

I then completely uninstalled that version and took the version from canonical.com and have now managed to successfully use Skype.