# Ubuntu 13.10 skype restore hidden icon on notification bar

Tags: icons, 13.10, skype, notification

After upgrading Ubuntu to version 13.10 in the notification bar next to the clock is missing the Skype icon.

[skype_hidden_icon1](http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/159/rk96.png)

[skype_hidden_icon2](http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/6596/40or.png)

how can I restore it?

thanks in advance

sorry for my bad en.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286233/how-to-add-a-skype-indicator

Comment: solved: apt-get install sni-qt sni-qt:i386

Comment: Another duplicate: [How to re-enable tray icons for applications in ubuntu 13.10?](http://askubuntu.com/q/362135/107321). (Contains best solution I found so far.)

Answer (score 2):

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and I found my answer here:
[How to add a Skype indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286233/how-to-add-a-skype-indicator)

What fixed it for me was the post from User "Jorrit" who made the following post:
"I had the same problem, installing the following package fixed it for me: sni-qt:i386"