# How to display the skype indicator on the status top-bar?

Tags: unity, indicator, skype

How do I to display the Skype indicator on the top bar, please?

I'm actually running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity.
Architecture: 64 bits.
And, I haven't customized my theme.

I've tried to follows these [tips](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286233/how-to-add-a-skype-indicator), but i've got nothing in response.

Thanks in advace!

Comment: try this then http://askubuntu.com/questions/151112/how-do-i-get-the-skype-status-icon-back-on-panel-tray

Comment: Geo, there is no panel under unity.