# System Tray and Ibus

Tags: unity, icons, ibus, system-tray

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 64bit. Recently I have installed an input-method in the internet which is ([Robo-iBus](https://github.com/BoGoEngine/ibus-bogo#introduction)). I depicted figure below, icon **bogo** above **English (US)**.  Later, I removed it from my machine but its icon in system tray is still there and I can switch from default method to it.

[image]

I have checked and removed in /usr/share/ibus. Also, I have check dconf-editor to find tray-whitelist but it may be removed (refer from [How to add a Skype indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286233/how-to-add-a-skype-indicator))

Edited: follow @A.B.'s comment below: ouput of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` is `[('ibus', 'bogo'), ('xkb', 'us')]`

My question is could you please give me any advice to remove it completely.

Comment: Which icon do you mean?

Comment: sorry, I have edited

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: yes, i did. Output is [('ibus', 'bogo'), ('xkb', 'us')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you said, the command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources source
```

gives you

```
[('ibus', 'bogo'), ('xkb', 'us')]
```

you have to correct the settings with the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us')]"
```

Maybe you have to restart Unity.

Comment: Great to hear that. You're welcome :)